# Stuck on Cryptopals Crypto Challenge 3 set 1

Tags: python-3.x, math, cryptography

I'm failry new to cryptography and programming as a whole ( mabey a few months) and i started the cryptopal challenges. I got the first 2 done correctly with alot of reading into how to convert things in python.

I'm getting stuck on the code for the 3rd one, "Single-Byte XOR" where they give you a hex string and tell you to write a program to find the key they used to XOR the string.

I am aware of how i would go about doing this (without looking solutions):
1) convert the string to binary
2) loop through all character values XORing them individually with the given ciphertext
3) checking these XORd results to see which one looks "the most english"

I guess im just confused on the way bytes behave in python.
here is my code:

```
my_ciphertext =    "1b37373331363f78151b7f2b783431333d78397828372d363c78373e783a393b3736"
binary_rep_of_ciphertext = binascii.unhexlify(my_ciphertext)
array_of_ciphertext = bytearray(binary_rep_of_ciphertext)

def xor_string_and_char(my_char_value):
    result = array_of_ciphertext ^ my_char_value
    return '{:x}'.format(result)     # convert back to hexadecimal

x = 0 
assert x==0
while x in range(255):
    my_plaintext = xor_string_and_char(x)
    print('b' + my_plaintext)
    x=x+1
```

Comment: Your algorithm is fine. To XOR every character in a string with a given byte value, try something like this: `plaintext = ''.join([chr(ord(ch) ^ char_value) for ch in my_string])`

Comment: Would you mind explaining what line(s) of code this would replace?

Comment: `result = array_of_ciphertext ^ my_char_value`, but operating on a string variable instead of a byte array. (If you're using a byte array, then replace `ord(ch)` with `ch` and you should be fine.)

Comment: Thank you for the input! I fixed it now, and am still getting used to converting types and XORing things.

Comment: No probs. And stick with it. Python's a lot of fun 